# ENA minion 2D data doesn't actually have 2D data

Tags: minion

I am looking at some [yeast ONT data](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/SAMEA2757769) from [De novo yeast genome assemblies from MinION, PacBio and MiSeq platforms, Giordano et al 2017](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-03996-z).

I noticed that the Minion fastq files have both a forward and reverse file. The methods paper says that these reads are from the SQK-MAP006 and SQK-MAP007 protocols which both appear to be 2D. Are these just the 2D forward and reverse files?

Still being unsure, I checked if this was true by counting the number of characters in each read.

```
>> zcat ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz | head -1
@ERR1883385.1 dc5b9de2-ba00-47ab-b698-8ad470704c0a_Basecall_2D_000_template EVO107591_Sanger_FAA52213_CBS432_Phenol_3a_4517_1_ch251_file44_strand/1

>> zcat ERR1883385_2.fastq.gz | head -1
@ERR1883385.1 dc5b9de2-ba00-47ab-b698-8ad470704c0a_Basecall_2D_000_template EVO107591_Sanger_FAA52213_CBS432_Phenol_3a_4517_1_ch251_file44_strand/2


>> zcat ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz | head -2 | awk '{ print length($0); }' -
147
1675

>> zcat ERR1883385_2.fastq.gz | head -2 | awk '{ print length($0); }' -
147
1693
```

As you can see, the read is the same but the forward and reverse strands are different lengths.

Is there some way to just download the `poretools` equivalent to  `2D` from ENA without having to download the fast5 files and extract them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. ENA doesn't have any ability to specifically flag a file as 2D, and the nanopore file formats have changed a lot, so you pretty much need to rely on the submitter to separate out the reads in a meaningful way.

Also, there wasn't really any consistent convention for what ONT used in their read headers. Looking at some of my old files they had a plain sequence ID (i.e. without anything suggesting temp/comp) in different template/complement folders in the FAST5 files for the components of a 2D read and the consensus sequence, but later changed it to _2D_template and _2D_complement as in the example you have (possibly with an intermediate _1D_template and _1D_complement format). Parsing/understanding those FAST5 files can be difficult, which is why poretools was created in the first place.

It's still a bit of a mess, with the 1D$^2$ reads ending up in a Frankenstein-like state that's partially 1D and partially 2D.